# Training Model in Caret Using F1 Metric

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to fit a random forest model to my dataset and I would like to select the best model based off of the F1 score. I saw a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37666516/caret-package-custom-metric) describing the code necessary. I attempted to copy the code but I am getting the error

> "Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "F1_Score"

while I run the train function. (FYI the variable I am trying to predict ("pass") is a two class factor "Fail" and "Pass")

See Code Below:

```
library(MLmetrics)
library(caret)
library(doSNOW)

f1 <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
  f1_val <- F1_Score(y_pred = data$pred, y_true = data$obs, positive = lev[1])
  c(F1 = f1_val)
}



train.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                              number = 10,
                              repeats = 3,
                              classProbs = TRUE,
                              summaryFunction = f1,
                              search = "grid")


tune.grid <- expand.grid(.mtry = seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1))


cl <- makeCluster(3, type = "SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
random.forest.orig <- train(pass ~ manufacturer+meter.type+premise+size+age+avg.winter+totalizer, 
                     data = meter.train,
                     method = "rf",
                     tuneGrid = tune.grid,
                     metric = "F1",
                     weights = model_weights,
                     trControl = train.control)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: In the post you have linked, the OP has defined a `F1_Score` function. Maybe you have not copied it.

Comment: The F1_Score function is defined in the MLmetrics library.

Answer (score 5):

I've rewritten the f1 function not using the MLmetrics library and it seems to work. See below for a working code to create a f1 score:

```
f1 <- function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
  precision <- posPredValue(data$pred, data$obs, positive = "pass")
  recall  <- sensitivity(data$pred, data$obs, postive = "pass")
  f1_val <- (2 * precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
  names(f1_val) <- c("F1")
  f1_val
} 

train.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                          number = 10,
                          repeats = 3,
                          classProbs = TRUE,
                          #sampling = "smote",
                          summaryFunction = f1,
                          search = "grid")


tune.grid <- expand.grid(.mtry = seq(from = 1, to = 10, by = 1))


cl <- makeCluster(3, type = "SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
random.forest.orig <- train(pass ~ manufacturer+meter.type+premise+size+age+avg.winter+totalizer, 
                 data = meter.train,
                 method = "rf",
                 tuneGrid = tune.grid,
                 metric = "F1",
                 trControl = train.control)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: There is also a function called `prSummary` that you can use to compute that metric.

Comment: with `prSummary` how can we change the cost of `FalseNegative` and `FalsePositive` ?

Comment: @joel.wilson "with prSummary how can we change the cost of FalseNegative and FalsePositive " The positive and negative classes are determined alphabetically by their class name so if for example your class names were "A" and "B" then your positive class would be "A".  If you need to keep "A" and "B" in your class names but you would like for "B" to be the positive class then you would need to do something like naming your classes "YA" and "XB."

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same error. The error also happened when I used other functions from the `MLmetrics` package, e.g., `Precision` function.

I solved it by accessing the `F1_Score` function using double colons `::`.

```
f1 <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
        f1_val <- MLmetrics::F1_Score(y_pred = data$pred,
                                      y_true = data$obs,
                                      positive = lev[1])
        c(F1 = f1_val)
}
```

Using `MLmetrics::F1_Score` you unequivocally work with the `F1_Score` from the `MLmetrics` package.

One advantage of `MLmetrics` package is that its functions work with variables that have more than 2 levels.