# Use F1 Score as metric for multiclass prediction

Tags: r, dataframe, r-caret, caret

I already found this [Training Model in Caret Using F1 Metric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820750/training-model-in-caret-using-f1-metric) were it is described how to use F1 as a metric using a custom summaryFunction.

However this only works with binary classifications. I would like to use it for a multi-class dataset.

What I have done so far is the following:

```
f1 <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
    print(data)
    precision <- posPredValue(data$pred, data$obs, positive = "pass")
    recall <- sensitivity(data$pred, data$obs, positive = "pass")
    f1_val <- (2*precision*recall) / (precision + recall)
    names(f1_val) <- c("F1")
    f1_val
}


train.control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                              number = 2,
                              summaryFunction = defaultSummary,
                              classProbs = TRUE, 
                              search = "grid")
                              
tune.grid <- expand.grid(.mtry = seq(from = 5, to = 10, by = 1))
                              
random.forest.orig <- train(target~.,
                            data = data.small,
                            method = "rf",
                            tuneGrid = tune.grid,
                            metric = "F1",
                            trControl = train.control)

random.forest.orig
```

As expected it produces the following error:

```
Error in posPredValue.default(data$pred, data$obs, positive = "pass") : input data must have the same two levels
```

My hope is that somebody already did this and can help me figuring it out. Otherwise I am also wondering why the data frame used in the f1 function only contains 10 rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

```
f1 <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
    f1_val <- f1_score(data$pred,data$obs)
    names(f1_val) <- c("F1")
    f1_val
}

f1_score <- function(predicted, expected, positive.class="1") {
    predicted <- factor(as.character(predicted), levels=unique(as.character(expected)))
    expected  <- as.factor(expected)
    cm = as.matrix(table(expected, predicted))

    precision <- diag(cm) / colSums(cm)
    recall <- diag(cm) / rowSums(cm)
    f1 <-  ifelse(precision + recall == 0, 0, 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall))

    #Assuming that F1 is zero when it's not possible compute it
    f1[is.na(f1)] <- 0

    #Binary F1 or Multi-class macro-averaged F1
    ifelse(nlevels(expected) == 2, f1[positive.class], mean(f1))
}


train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                              number = 2,
                              summaryFunction = f1,
                              classProbs = TRUE, 
                              search = "grid")
                              
tune.grid <- expand.grid(.mtry = seq(from = 10, to = 15, by = 1))
                              
random.forest.orig <- train(target~.,
                            data = data.small,
                            method = "rf",
                            tuneGrid = tune.grid,
                            metric = "F1",
                            trControl = train.control)

random.forest.orig
```

hope it helps somebody