# How do I compute weighted macro f1-score and micro f1-score in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I am running some random forest classification models with caret (using ranger). I am looping through various dependent variables who all have five levels. It is therefore a multi-classification problem. Several of my variables suffer from rather big class imbalances. Right now, I am training the ranger model in caret using a custom f1 function and summaryFunction = f1 (like the one presented here [Training Model in Caret Using F1 Metric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820750/training-model-in-caret-using-f1-metric) )

The code for the f1 function (for training) looks like this (together with the code for training the actual model):

```
f1 <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
  f1_val <- MLmetrics::F1_Score(y_pred = data$pred,
                                y_true = data$obs,
                                positive = lev[1])
  c(F1 = f1_val)
}

traincntr <- trainControl(method = "cv", 
                          number = 5,
                          search = "grid",  
                          verboseIter = TRUE,
                          summaryFunction = f1,
                          classProbs = TRUE,
                          allowParallel = TRUE)

fit_rf <-  caret::train(y = y,
                          x = predictors,
                          method = 'ranger',
                          metric = "F1",
                          tuneGrid = tuning_grid_rf,         
                          trControl = traincntr,
                          importance = "permutation",
                          verbose = TRUE)
```

After, when evaluating the models prediction on the test set, I run the following custom function (also from the link above):

```
f1_score <- function(predicted, expected, positive.class="1") {
  predicted <- factor(as.character(predicted), levels=unique(as.character(expected)))
  expected  <- as.factor(expected)
  cm = as.matrix(table(expected, predicted))
  
  precision <- diag(cm) / colSums(cm)
  recall <- diag(cm) / rowSums(cm)
  f1 <-  ifelse(precision + recall == 0, 0, 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall))
  
  #Assuming that F1 is zero when it's not possible compute it
  f1[is.na(f1)] <- 0
  
  #Binary F1 or Multi-class macro-averaged F1
  ifelse(nlevels(expected) == 2, f1[positive.class], mean(f1))
}
```

How do I turn either the f1 metric used for training ("f1") or the one used after predicting on the test set ("f1_score") into a weighted f1 metric?

Comment: Use the [`MLmetrics::FBeta_Score`](https://rdrr.io/cran/MLmetrics/man/FBeta_Score.html) when defining the `F_beta` function and use a predefined beta of your choosing. I do not think caret supports passing arguments to performance metrics. If the comment is unclear please tell me and I can post a more detailed answer.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean. You mean that instead of MLmetrics::F1_score I should use MLmetrics::FBeta_Score when defining the f1 score I use as the metric in for hyperparameter tuning in caret? And is FBeta_Score applicable to multiclass problems (so not binary outcome)?

Comment: It looks like I did not read the question carefully. The best way to do this would be to implement a multiclass F1 score and use it directly for scoring in caret. The function  [`multiROC::multi_pr`](https://rdrr.io/cran/multiROC/man/multi_pr.html) calculates micro and macro Recall and Precision. Some data munging is needed to get the correct input from caret `data` object but not too much. After you calculate the mentioned metrics it should be fairly easy to return the [F1 score](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-metrics-made-simple-part-ii-the-f1-score-ebe8b2c2ca1).

Comment: another function you can look at is [`mltest::ml_test`](https://rdrr.io/cran/mltest/man/ml_test.html). It computes the per class metrics, end then you can combine them to suit your needs.